# Camel: Omitting parts of a route depending on where the message comes from

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have two routes:

```
.from("A")
.to("C")
.to("B");

.from("C")
*some processing logic*
.to("D");
```

Is it possible to build the second route such that:

- when the message comes from the first route, some or all parts of the logic are ommited;
- when the message comes to the second route directly, the logic is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set exchange properties on route(s). Then you can evaluate the values inside filter or choice to branch or alter the routing logic. I would advice against anything more complex than this to avoid unnecessary coupling between routes.

**Example:**

```java
package org.example;

import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleRouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnSentBody() throws Exception {
     
        final String testMessage = "AAAA";

        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultMockEndpoint.message(0).body().isEqualTo(testMessage);

        template.sendBody("direct:a", testMessage);

        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnBBBB() throws Exception {
     
        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultMockEndpoint.message(0).body().isEqualTo("BBBB");

        template.sendBody("direct:b", null);

        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
    

                from("direct:a")
                    .setProperty("From", constant("A"))
                    .to("direct:c");
                    
                from("direct:b")
                    .setProperty("From", constant("B"))
                    .to("direct:c");

                from("direct:c")
                    .filter(exchangeProperty("From").isNotEqualTo("A"))
                        .log("Processing message")
                        .setBody(constant("BBBB"))
                    .end()
                    .log("body: ${body}")
                    .to("mock:result");
                
            }
        };
    }
}
```